# Need help on network related error connecting to sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have encountered a problem with an application that needs to connect to a database. Here are some of my connection strings:

```
 public static SqlConnection CustomerDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabasePath + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

 public static SqlConnection TemplateDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + TemplateVariables.TemplateDatabasePath + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

using the following code to get a path for the CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabasePath:

```
 public static string baseDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\");

 public static string CustomerDatabasePath =  System.IO.Path.Combine(GeneralVariables.baseDirectory, "CustomerDatabase.mdf");
```

I then use the following data adapter code:

```
 public static string CustomerDatabaseSQL = "SELECT* From " + AccountVariables.Username;

 public static SqlDataAdapter CustomerDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabaseSQL, CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabaseConnection);
```

However I get the following error when I try to fill in the Data adapter:

```
 CustomerVariables.CustomerDataAdapter.Fill(customersDatabaseDataSet);
```

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: have you followed the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Check your connection string http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Is your SQL database running? Can you connect to it through a query tool like SQL Management Studio?

Comment: check if you can connect to the database from SQL Management Studio. If yes, then check your connection string.

Comment: The title of this question has nothing to do with the text of the question, both have nothing to do with the root cause i.e. the error message.

Comment: You say `Server=localhost;` - are you sure it isn't a named instance (like `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;`)? Are you connecting successfully from Management Studio?

Comment: I do not really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the .mdf in the original connection strings such as

```
public static SqlConnection CustomerDatabaseConnection = new  SqlConnection("Server=localhost;" + "Database=CustomerDatabase.mdf");
```

The .mdf should be removed from the original connection strings if typed data tables were created to the data from all users and use table adaptors to update these, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the SQL Server service is running, most probably it is not.

Press Windows Key + R and type services.msc in the Run window then run the SQL Server service

Comment: Is this the SQL Server VSS Writer

Comment: No, its Microsoft SQL Server, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx) might help

Comment: I don't seem to have the sql server in the services.msc

Comment: Are you sure Microsoft SQL Server is installed on your machine ?

Comment: I've just decided to install SQL server express as i could not find it.

Comment: I've added the sql server and got it running. However, the error still pops up when I run my application

Comment: The path for the customer database is "C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Customer Manager application\Customer Manager application\bin\Debug\CustomerDatabase.mdf" but the CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabasePath uses the path "C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Customer Manager application\CustomerDatabase.mdf

Comment: this is not a connection string, MDF is the database file, a connection string looks like
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=sa

Comment: How would you get this connection string?

Comment: Did that provide an answer for your question ?

Comment: Not really it still did not recognoise any connection string format, I put in.However when I did put an @ next to the connection string "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + CustomerVariables.CustomerDatabasePath + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" it comes up with the error "Incorrect syntax near 'From'"